# Extjs date format issue safari firefox

Tags: google-chrome, date, firefox, extjs, safari

Dates are stored in the format, `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in the database.

```
e.g.  2014-07-03 00:00:00
```

But I want my `Ext.Field.Date` to have the format:

```
Y-m-d H:i
```

As per my component set up:

```
 xtype: 'datefield',
 id: 'p_p_start',
 fieldLabel: 'Planned Start',
 name: 'plannedstart',
 allowBlank: false,
 vtypeText: 'Date not valid',
 format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
```

It is quite reasonable of me to want to be able to display the date in browsers other than just Chrome. To-date, FireFox and Safari will display nothing.

I've looked at a similar issue on SO which proposed support of all browser by splitting and reassembling the string format in a variation of:

```
var c=Ext.getCmp('p_p_start');
var st_date = "2014-05-08";// with alt formats changed Y-m-d, leaving time out diags
var dateParts = st_date.split(/-/);
var d = new Date(dateParts[0],parseInt( dateParts[1], 10) -1,dateParts[2]);
console.log("Date parts= " + dateParts);//Date parts= 2014,05,08 
c.setValue(  d ); //NOPE!
```

I was very happy with progress in Chrome (no problems at all) but have yet to succeed in getting anything working in FF or Safari (not tried IE but it has to work in that also). So, in summary, the question is, 
How do I get date formats in all browsers to work with the format `Y-m-d H:i` using `setValue`?

Many thanks in advance.

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

A date field's internal value is a [JavaScript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which is not tied to a specific format. The [`format`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-format) config simply defines the display and input format of the field.

You **can** use `setValue` with a string, but only if the string already conforms to your defined `format`.

In your case the problem seems to be converting a date string value with a **different** format which was received from the server/database to a Date object.

Have a look at the [`Ext.Date`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date) singleton, specifically its function [`Ext.Date.parse`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-parse), to achieve that:

```
var st_date = "2014-05-08";
var dateObj = Ext.Date.parse(st_date, "Y-m-d");
Ext.getCmp('p_p_start').setValue(dateObj);

var st_date2 = "2014-07-03 00:00:00";
var dateObj2 = Ext.Date.parse(st_date2, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
Ext.getCmp('p_p_start').setValue(dateObj2);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. It doesn't solve the safari/ff problem but works in Chrome.  
var dateObj2 = Ext.Date.parse("2014-05-08 00:00", "Y-m-d H:i");
console.log("dateObj = " + dateObj2); //dateObj = Thu May 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) 
Ext.getCmp('p_p_start').setValue(dateObj2);
I got some good pointers from you though. Will keep trying.

Comment: Actually this code should work in all major browsers, including Firefox and Safari. Check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/603), which works for me in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari. Btw, which ExtJS version are you using?

Comment: It does work in Jsfiddle on all browsers - exactly as you say - so its something wrong in my app. I'm on 4.2.x using Sencha Architect 3.0.4.1386 cmd 4.0.4.84. I changed the version on jsfiddle also and the problem is not apparent there. Again, thanks for the effort in helping me track this down.

Comment: Embarassing. I was running FireBug and it seems it does render the value but it an event fires on another component which tries to change the 00:00 part of the date in p_p_start which causes it to go blank. I was thrown by the fact that it works in chrome but not other browsers. I'll change the code in such a way that it works across them all. Thanks again @matt Kevin